# Python Opencv+Gdal

Tags: python, array, numpy

Estoy desarrollando un software para calcular NDVI. 
Que es NDVI? es un calculo matemático con el cual se puede determinar el nivel de estrés de la vegetación
NDVI = NIR-RED/NIR+RED
Este resultado varia de -1 a 1
Estoy usando OpenCV como librería para visión artificial y Gdal para ayudar a los cálculos.

Mi idea es poder "colorear" los rangos que entregue NDVI, por ejemplo para valores < 0 colorear esos pixeles con un color rojo.

Mi problema es que no puedo recorrer la matriz de datos.

Les adjunto el codigo:

```
# Importamos Librerias a utilizar
from osgeo import gdal
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Abrimos la imagen a utilizar
img = cv2.imread('image01.JPG')
# Pasamos de RGB a HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# Claros
lw_range = np.array([4, 150, 0])
# Oscuros
up_range = np.array([34, 255, 255])
#Crear una mascara con solo los pixeles dentro del rango de verdes
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lw_range, up_range)
# resta para mostrar imagen original
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask)
cv2.imwrite('imglimpia.tif',res)

# Procesamiento con Gdal
imgGedal = gdal.Open('imglimpia.tif', gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
num_bands = imgGedal.RasterCount
rows = imgGedal.RasterYSize
cols = imgGedal.RasterXSize
#print('Numero de Bandas {n}\n'.format(n=num_bands))

# Separamos por banda
blue  = imgGedal.GetRasterBand(3)
green = imgGedal.GetRasterBand(2)
red   = imgGedal.GetRasterBand(1)

blue_data  = blue.ReadAsArray()
green_data = green.ReadAsArray()
red_data   = red.ReadAsArray()
cv2.imwrite('azul.tif',blue_data)
cv2.imwrite('gren.tif',green_data)
cv2.imwrite('red.tif',red_data)

# Obtener Valores Minimo y Maximo
band_min, band_max, band_mean, band_stddev = blue.GetStatistics(0, 1)
print('Rango Azul: Minimo: {minimo} - Medio: {medio} - Maximo: {maximo} - Tamano: {sz}- STDDEV: {stddev}'
    .format(maximo=band_max,medio=blue_data.mean(),minimo=band_min,sz=blue_data.shape,stddev=band_stddev))


band_min, band_max, band_mean, band_stddev = green.GetStatistics(0, 1)
print('Rango Verde: Minimo: {minimo} - Medio: {medio} - Maximo: {maximo} - Tamano: {sz}- STDDEV: {stddev}'
    .format(maximo=band_max,medio=blue_data.mean(),minimo=band_min,sz=blue_data.shape,stddev=band_stddev))


band_min, band_max, band_mean, band_stddev = red.GetStatistics(0, 1)
print('Rango Rojo: Minimo: {minimo} - Medio: {medio} - Maximo: {maximo} - Tamano: {sz}- STDDEV: {stddev}'
    .format(maximo=band_max,medio=blue_data.mean(),minimo=band_min,sz=blue_data.shape,stddev=band_stddev))


# Calcular NDVI = ((Nir-Blue)/(Nir+Blue))
resta = cv2.subtract(red_data,blue_data)
suma = cv2.add(red_data,blue_data)
ndvi = cv2.divide(resta,suma)
print 'NDVI MIN   : ',ndvi.min()
print 'NDVI MEDIO : ',ndvi.mean()
print 'NDVI MAX   : ',ndvi.max()
```

Luego de esto, quiero recorrer el array de datos para colorear pixeles

```
# Creamos los colores
greenyellow = [4,255,173]
yellow = [0,255,255]
yellowred = [4,111,255]
green = [0,255,0]
greenyellow = [0,255,146]
blue = [255,0,0]
red = [0,0,255]
white = [255,255,255]
black = [0,0,0]

y = np.zeros((4000,3000,3),np.uint8)  # img coloreada
cols,rows,band = y.shape
for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            for k in ndvi[i,j]:
                print (str([i,j,k]) + '\n')
                if k < 0.0 :
                    y[i,j] = red
                    break
                if 0.0 < k < 0.2 :
                    y[i,j] = yellowred
                    break
                if 0.2 < k < 0.4 :
                    y[i,j] = yellow
                    break
                if 0.4 < k < 0.6 :
                    y[i,j] = greenyellow
                    break
                if k > 0.6 :
                    y[i,j] = green
                    break
                else:
                    y[i,j] = black
                    break
cv2.imwrite('NDVI.jpg',y)
```

este es el error que me genera:

```
for k in ndvi[j,i]:
TypeError: 'numpy.uint8' object is not iterable
```

Comment: El título puede ser un poco engañoso ya que el uso de openCV y gdal no parecen estar relacionados con el problema en sí. Quizá sería conveniente que cambiaras el título a algo más apropiado.

Comment: porque no?
La utilización de opencv es para limpiar la img y gdal para calcular ndvi

Comment: pero el error te lo da al operar con `numpy`. Ni `gdal` ni `openCV` te dan error.

Comment: tu haz calculado ndvi?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que `ndvi` es un *ndarray* de 2 dimensiones y cuando asignas valores a ambos índices te devuelve el *item* para esa posición del *ndarray* y eso no es iterable y es un escalar (`np.uint8`) y, por tanto, el `for` se 'rompe' ya que no puede iterar sobre el escalar.

**EDIT:**

Además, `ndvi` es un array con forma 3000 x 4000 y el que estás creando para rellenar, `y`, es de 4000x3000 por lo que se llega al límite en una de las dimensiones.

Corrijo el código de más abajo:

Directamente, en los bucles deberías hacer:

```
y = np.zeros((3000,4000,3),np.uint8)  # img coloreada
rows,cols,band = y.shape
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        k = ndvi[i,j] ## QUITAMOS EL BUCLE PARA 'k'
        print (str([i,j,k]) + '\n')
        if k < 0.0 :
            y[i,j] = red
            break
        if 0.0 < k < 0.2 :
            y[i,j] = yellowred
            break
        if 0.2 < k < 0.4 :
            y[i,j] = yellow
            break
        if 0.4 < k < 0.6 :
            y[i,j] = greenyellow
            break
        if k > 0.6 :
            y[i,j] = green
            break
        else:
            y[i,j] = black
            break
```

El resultado final que veo es una imagen en negro por lo que creo que algo del algoritmo debe andar mal, pero ahora, por lo menos, se ejecuta el código completo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu Respuesta.
Mira hice lo que me comentaste, imprimí  con "print (str([i,j,k]) + '\n')"
todo bien.
[0, 2998, 0.0]

[0, 2999, 0.0]

[1, 0, 0.0]

[1, 1, 0.0]

Hace todo bien, pero al agregar las lineas para colorear salta un error.
k = ndvi[i,j] ## QUITAMOS EL BUCLE PARA 'k'
IndexError: index 3000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3000

Comment: Sin saber la imagen que estás usando es difícil poder decirte mucho más. El error es claro, las dimensiones de `ndvi` no son las mismas que las que usas en `cols` y `rows`. Para llegar a `ndvi` realizas una serie de operaciones, comprueba la forma del array, `ndvi.shape`, para ver que las dimensiones no son compatibles. Otra opción es que dejes una imagen de ejemplo para poder reproducir el error...

Comment: Ok, dejare el enlace del drive
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwYIvc8KD9beMWtrU0tKSmVMREE

Esa es la imagen que estoy utilizando

Comment: No tengo gdal instalado ni posibilidad de instalarlo ahora mismo (de viaje). A ver si otros te pueden ayudar pero el problema creo que está claro. Las dimensiones no coinciden y/o se modifican en algún momento.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta a ver si ya eres capaz de ejecutarlo.

Comment: si, al final me di cuenta de eso. Muchas Gracias por tu tiempo